# Maxmind ip to city - mysql indexing

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use maxmind database to find out the city of some ip. (http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity)
There are 2 tables:
1st table columns:
startIpNum,endIpNum,locId
2nd table columns:
locId,country,region,city,postalCode,latitude,longitude,metroCode,areaCode
Quick explanation:
I use the first table to get the location id of the table and then I can get the info of that location from the second table. Ok, let's forget about the second part of the process. In order to accomplish the first part I'm using mysql and to get the locId I use the next code.

```
SELECT locId FROM first_table WHERE startIpNum<=IP and endIpNum>=IP LIMIT 1
```

Where IP is a*256*256*256+b*256*256+c*256+d (from ip => a.b.c.d, example 197.248.67.1, a=197, b=248... and so on) this means that we're talking about comparisons between integers.
Here is the problem, this operation is too slow. My second thought was using an index, so I tried to use an index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX test ON first_table ( startIpNum,endIpNum,locId)
```

Maybe it's not the best index of the world, but I thought that was the best solution to my problem... and well... it's not. The process is still pretty slow like 10 seconds. Any ideas????
By the way, this table has almost 3.5 Millions of rows. But I know the problem it's the operator less than and more than, but I don't know what else I can do.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Some things aren't clear from your question:

Does it take 10 seconds to look up 1 IP?

How many IP addresses are you looking to find the city of?

Are those two tables created from the maxmind CSV format, or are they your data?

Did you use the CSV Format of the maxmind database?  I would suggest using the binary format, it is much faster.

Comment: like 6 millions,I found that i can do it with mysql GIS, so I'll be working on it in a couple of days...